# A Family of Bases for a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a multiset of $kn$ nonzero vectors in $\mathbf{R}^n$.  Suppose that for $1 \leq d \leq n$, each $d$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbf{R}^n$ contains at most $kd$ members of $V$.  Then $V$ can be partitioned into $k$ bases of $\mathbf{R}^n$.

A proof or a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to look up the matroid partitioning theorems of Edmonds.

Comment: @Andy B, why not write that as an answer?  Here's a link to a reprint of one of Edmonds's papers with an introduction by Edmonds: http://www.iasi.cnr.it/jack/material/(06)_Matroid_Partitioning.pdf see the discussion on page 210(338 of the original scan).

Comment: See also http://books.google.com/books?id=mqGeSQ6dJycC&pg=PA728&lpg=PA728#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the question was answered in the comments:  Edmonds proves a more general theorem for a family of matroids.  If the matroids are all the same and if that matroid is a vector matroid, then it is exactly the question stated.